# Cannot run npm install on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, ubuntu-18.04

```
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

Above is the error I get when running npm install on ubuntu. I have node version 16.13.2 and ubuntu is version 18.04.

I tried adding following to package json but it did not work.

```
{
        "engines": {
         "node": ">= 16.13.2"
},
```

I also tried the following on ubunutu command line

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

but, it did not work. It says I have the latest version already that is, 2.27-3ubuntu1.5 but the error mentions 2.28 is required. Cannot find how to update.

Comment: what is your output for `node -v` ?

Answer (score 15):

Maybe you are using latest version of node (18.0.0) . It created same error for me .
Use node js stable release or the version you are sure that will work.you can use `n` to install various nodejs verson.
you can install n using npm `sudo npm i -g n` after that run
`sudo n stable`  or `sudo n <node version you needed>`

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. Thank you

Comment: when I run :
sudo npm i -g n 
I get:
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)